# Вывод значения селектора

Tags: javascript

На странице есть селектор:

```
                            <select id="1">
                            <option value="1" >1</option>
                            <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            </select>
```

Функция, которая забирает значения из селектора

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#1").change(function() {
                    CoinProd = $('#1').val();

                    Filter();
                });
            });
```

Функция фильтр, которая фильтрует таблицу

```
function Filter() {
                var Pair = CoinProd + '/' + CoinVal;
                if (CoinProd="All"){
                    console.log("All")
                }
                Row_Orders_Table = document.getElementsByClassName('my__table-row');

                for (var i = 0; i < Row_Orders_Table.length; i++) {
                    Row_Orders_Table[i].classList.add('hide');
                    if ((Row_Orders_Table[i].querySelector('.my__table-a').innerHTML == Pair) && ((Row_Orders_Table[i].querySelector('.my__table-b').getAttribute("name") == Orders_Type) || (Orders_Type == "All")) && ((Row_Orders_Table[i].querySelector('.my__table-z').innerHTML == Orders_Status) || (Orders_Status == "History")) && (((parseInt(+new Date()) - (Row_Orders_Table[i].querySelector('.my__table-t').getAttribute('name')).split('_')[1]) <= Orders_Time) || (Orders_Time == null))) {
                        Row_Orders_Table[i].classList.remove('hide');

                    }
                }
            }
```

Почему при любом выборе в селекторе, в консоль выводится сообщение ALL из функции filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что надо

```
if (CoinProd === "All"){
    console.log("All")
}
```

Вы не сравниваете значения, а присваиваете в условии.

Comment: ночь, видимо поплавило, спасибо)